# Confused about "override" vs. "new" in C#

Tags: c#, virtual, overriding, new-operator

I'm having the following classes:

```
class Base
{
    public virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base");
    }
}

class Der1 : Base
{
    public new virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Der1");
    }
}

class Der2 : Der1
{
    public override void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Der2");
    }
}
```

This is my main method:

```
Base b = new Der2();
Der1 d1 = new Der2();
Der2 d2 = new Der2();

b.Print();
d1.Print();
d2.Print();
```

The output is `Base`, `Der2`, `Der2`.

As far as I know, Override won't let previous method to run, even if the pointer is pointing to them. So the first line should output `Der2` as well. However `Base` came out.

How is it possible? How the override didn't work there?

Comment: Really An Amazing example...
The only trick here is:-
 intially, method of BASE's was hidden by the virtual method of "Der-1", so over-ride method of "Der-2" could NOT be implemented. Thus, we got the BASE's value.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**You've never actually overriden the `Base` version of `Print()`. You've only hidden it with a separate virtual method (named the same) in `Der1`.**

When you use the `new` keyword on a method signature - you are telling the compiler that this is a method that happens to have the same name as a method of one of your base classes - but has no other relation. You can make this new method virtual (as you've done) but that's not the same as overriding the base class method.

In `Der2` when you override `Print` you are actually overriding the 'new' version that you declared in `Der1` - not the version is `Base`. Eric Lippert has an [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508350/why-does-this-polymorphic-c-code-print-what-it-does/1510702#1510702) to a slightly different question that may help you reason about how virtual methods are treated in the C# language.

In your example, when you call `Print`, you are calling it in the first case through a reference of type `Base` - so the hidden (but not overriden) version of `Print` is called. The other two calls are dispatched to `Der1`'s  implementation, because in this case, you've actually overriden the method.

You can read more about this in the [MSDN documentation of new and override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fawty39(VS.80).aspx).

What you may have intended to do with Der1 (as you did with Der2) is to use the `override` keyword:

```
class Base 
{ 
    public virtual void Print() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Base"); 
    } 
} 

class Der1 : Base 
{ 
    // omitting 'new' and using override here will override Base
    public override void Print() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Der1"); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: That's what he did with Der2.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy - indeed, that was my point. That's probably what was intended in Der1 as well, but somehow the `new` keyword was slipped in, instead of `override`. I'll update my post to make that more clear.

Comment: Thank you. An wonderful answer, I fully understood how it works now.

Comment: For what it's worth, situations like this - and the confusion they cause - are precisely why the compiler should *not* tell you by default, "Oh, just put 'new' on it..."  (CS0108: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s8070fc%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) because that is almost *never* what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 6):

It's because `Der1` does not *override* `Print`, *it replaces it with a brand new method that happens to have the same name* (this is caused by the use of the [`new`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4(VS.71).aspx#vclrfnew_newmodifier) keyword). So, when the object is cast to `Base` it calls `Print` in `Base`; there is no override to call..

Answer (score 1):

`override` will replace the previous method, but as your `Der1` class doesn't override `Print()` (it Shadows it, to use a VB-ism), then the most overriden verion of `Base`'s `Print()` is called, which happens to be the version it defines

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has said the class `Der1` is replacing `Print()` instead of overriding it.  To see this in action you could base `d1` and `d2` to `Base` and then call the print method.  It will then return `Base`.

```
((Base)d2).Print(); //Base
```