# Call a method in child of child class

Tags: c#, .net, abstract

I have three classes. First of them is abstract, and it is inherited by child class, which is again inherited. How to call method from the third class in abstract one?

Example code:

```
public abstract class DoSth
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm doing something");
        this.DoSomethingBigger();
    }
    protected abstract void DoSomethingBigger();
}

public class Writer : DoSth
{
    protected override void DoSomethingBigger()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm writting");
    }
}

public class BookWriter : Writer
{
    protected new void DoSomethingBigger()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm writting a book");
    }
}
```

How to call `DoSomethingBigger()` from a `BookWriter` class?
When I make an instance of a `BookWriter` and I call `DoSomething()` my output is

```
I'm doing something
I'm writting
```

but I want

```
I'm doing something
I'm writting a book
```

Comment: You are not overriding the method in the 3rd class, you are basically creating an entirely new method that the base knows nothing about. Did you mean to override it instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confused about "override" vs. "new" in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952887/confused-about-override-vs-new-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not overriding the method in the 3rd class, you are basically creating an entirely new method that the base knows nothing about. see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords) for more info. It's no different than changing the name of the method in `BookWriter` to something completely different like `DoSomethingElseAltogether()`, now it's much more obvious that you cannot call it from the base class.

Instead, you should override in the third class:

```
public class BookWriter : Writer
{
    protected override void DoSomethingBigger()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm writting a book");
    }
}
```

Comment: might I add that you probably want to `base.DoSomething()` to ensure it does what's in the superclass too

Comment: @Persistence Well maybe, depends on your use case. OP doesn't have it in the middle class, and if they did, I don't think it's what is required here.

Answer (score 2):

By marking your `DoSomethingBigger` method with `new` keyword you hide the initial `DoSomethingBigger` method instead of overriding it.

You should rewrite your code this way for it to work

```
public abstract class DoSth
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm doing something");
        this.DoSomethingBigger();
    }
    protected abstract void DoSomethingBigger();
}

public class Writer : DoSth
{
    protected override void DoSomethingBigger()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm writting");
    }
}

public class BookWriter : Writer
{
    protected override void DoSomethingBigger()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm writting a book");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pavel You cannot have `virtual` and `override` in the same method signature. This code doesn't compile.

Comment: Nice to hear that :)