# How to have a default method while still be able to override it?

Tags: c#

This is a C# project.

I have several classes inherited from a base class. Most of the child classes have the same behavior while some of them behave differently.

I'm using the `new` keyword.

```
public class Parent
{
    public DataTable FetchScore()
    {
        // blahblah
    }
}

public class ChildNormal : Parent
{
}

public class ChildOdd : Parent
{
    public new DataTable FetchScore()
    {
        DataTable dt = base.FetchScore();
        // blahblah
    }
}
```

But the build says using `new` is not a good practice.

I cannot use `virtual` and `override` either, because I want a default. I don't want to copy the same override implementation many times.

How do I do this in C#?

Comment: You can use virtual and override, just place the virtual base methods in the base class.

Comment: Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046387/exact-difference-between-overriding-and-hiding) for *why* using `new` is (probably) not what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the base `virtual` (which means it can be overridden if necessary) and `override` it where you need different behavior from the original. The non-overridden derived class will behave just like the base class.

```
public class Parent()
{
    public virtual DataTable FetchScore()
    {
        // blahblah
    }
}

public class ChildNormal() : Parent
{
}

public class ChildOdd() : Parent
{
    public override DataTable FetchScore()
    {
        DataTable dt = base.FetchScore();
        // blahblah
    }
}
```